# How to create views.py for multiple models including many-to-many

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm new to Python and DjangoRestFramework. I am trying to create an image upload system with image-tagging. "Tags" have a many-to-many relationship with "Images". The forms are in the React.js in the front-end. I am trying to understand how to write a view for this. I have not seen a clear solution to this online.

**here is upload/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import UUIDField
from django.contrib.postgres.functions import RandomUUID


def upload_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['images', str(instance.contributor), str(instance.caption), str(instance.date_created), filename])


class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.User', related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='user0')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=RandomUUID, editable=False)
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Image, through='Junction')

class Junction(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ForeignKey(Tags, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**upload/serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Image, Theme, Tags, Junction


class TagsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.PrimaryRelatedKeyField(
        queryset=Image.object.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ('Tags')


class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags_list = TagsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', 'contributor', 'caption', 'date_created', 'id')

class JunctionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Junction
        fields = ('image', 'theme', 'tags')
```

**Here are two possible solutions for the upload/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import JunctionSerializer
from .models import Image, Tags, Junction

#SOLUTION_1:
class JunctionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = JunctionSerializer
    query_set = Junction.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            image = request.data['cover']
            tags = request.data['tags']
       
            Junction.objects.create(image=image, tags=tags)
            return HttpResponse({'message': 'Successful Upload'}, status=200)


#SOLUTION_2
class JunctionView():
    
    ????

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(JunctionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['image'] = Image.objects.all()
        context['tags'] = Tags.objects.all()
        return context
```

Is it necessary to call the context? The second solution that I researched is not specific to Django REST Framework, I think..

Comment: You can create a model serializer for `Image`, which accepts a list of tags

Comment: I just copied the serializers.py code above. I believe I did this..

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a `ModelViewSet` for the images, since you are working mainly with managing the images.

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    query_set = Image.objects.all()
```

And then using your serializer, just modify your serializer to handle the m2m relations with a through model as described [`here`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model). So something like:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags_list = TagsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', 'contributor', 'caption', 'date_created', 'id')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_list = validated_data.pop('tags_list')
        instance = super().create(validated_data)

        for tag in tags_list:
            Junction.objects.create(image=instance, tag=tag)
```

This is not tested so it might have some problems here and there but this is the gist.

Comment: Thanks @bdbd. Would I not need to the ```def get_context_data ``` and to return an ```HttpResponse``` in ```ImageView``` if I follow your recommendation?

Comment: Sorry, I think I have to repost this question because I had to make my model more complex for multiple image upload. I will copy the link here.

Comment: Here is the new question. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68442655/creating-serializer-and-views-for-multiple-image-upload-and-many-to-many-relatio]

Comment: @Jie-LiangLin Please accept this answer if it answered this question.