# creating serializer and views for multiple image upload and many-to-many relations to tags

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-serializer

I had to repost [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422975/how-to-create-views-py-for-multiple-models-including-many-to-many/68433778#68433778) because my model became more complex.

I am trying to create a multiple image upload with image-tagging. "Tags" have a many-to-many relationship with "Images". The forms are in the React.js in the front-end. I am trying to understand how to write a serializer and view for this. I have not seen a clear solution to this online.

**upload/models.py**

```
from django.db.models.fields import UUIDField
from django.contrib.postgres.functions import RandomUUID


def upload_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['images', str(instance.image), str(instance.hashtags), str(instance.shape), instance.date_created, filename, filename, ])


class Themes(models.Model):
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=None)


class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.User', related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='0')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=RandomUUID, editable=False)


class Shape(models.Model):
    shape = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.User', related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='0')
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=RandomUUID, editable=False)


class HashTags(models.Model):
    hashtag = models.ManyToManyField(Image, through='Post', default=None)


class Post(models.Model):
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Themes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shape = models.ForeignKey(Shape, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hashtags = models.ForeignKey(
        HashTags, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    upload_data = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload_to')
```

**upload/serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Image, Shape, HashTags, Post, Themes

class ThemesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model: Themes
        fields: ('theme')

class HashTagsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HashTags
        fields = ('hashtag')


class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hashtags_list = HashTagsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', 'contributor', 'caption', 'id')


class ShapeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Shape
        fields = ('shape', 'contributor', 'id')


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('image', 'shape', 'hashtags', 'upload_data', 'date_created')
```

**Views.py**

```
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from .models import Post


class PostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    query_set = Post.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        image = request.data['image']
        shape = request.data['shape']
        tags = request.data['hashtags']
        upload_data = request.data['upload_data']
        date_created = request.data['date_created']

        Post.objects.create(image=image,
                            shape=shape, upload_data=upload_data, date_created=date_created, tags=tags)
        return HttpResponse({'message': 'Successful Upload'}, status=200)
```

I set the Views to the intermediate table `POST` because it compiles all the information for the Post request.

QUESTION: Is this the correct way to create a views for the model?

Comment: Using Post as the through model will cause you to end up with 1 post per hashtag, or 1 post per image. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, in one post, all the data should go together in one table. I started out with one simple upload model for Image, something like:

`class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.User', related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='0')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=RandomUUID, editable=False)
    tags = ..
    themes = ..
`

but then I realized that Tags should probably have a many-to-many relationship to the Image.

Comment: How do I do this properly?